# search within multiole .png filenames using list of multiple search patterns and copy results to new folder

Tags: linux, perl, find

I have a file called search.txt containing multiple search patterns

example "search.txt"  (Over 300 entries in total):

```
A28
A32
A3C
A46
A50
A5A
898
8A2
8AC
8B6
8C0
```

Example files from folder I want to search (Over 5000 in total):

```
 1_0_1_4AB_3_56_300000_0_0_0.png
 1_0_1_5A0_20_56_300000_0_0_0.png
 1_0_1_A28_22_56_300000_0_0_0.png
 1_0_1_A32_22_56_300000_0_0_0.png
 1_0_1_A96_23_56_300000_0_0_0.png
 1_0_1_898_21_56_300000_0_0_0.png
```

I need to check the fourth string of all .png's against all entries in search.txt (The strings are devided by "_")
I used a perl script similar to this before:

match4th.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
my $pat = qr/$ARGV[0]/;
while (<STDIN>) {
    my (undef, undef, undef, $fourth) = split /_/;
    print if defined($fourth) && $fourth =~ $pat;
}
```

Then I would use something like this to execute the sccript and move matching files to new location:

```
cd /png_folder
find . -name '*.png' | perl match4th.pl '/tmp/search.txt' | xargs mv -t /tmp/results
```

The part I am unsure about is how to tell the find command to use all entries in /tmp/search.txt rather than writing each pattern into the find command
I would also prefer to copy the files rather than move them

Comment: Check `perldoc -f glob` if you don't have png in subdirectories (File::Find otherwise), and File::Copy for moving or copying

Comment: GNU `cp` also takes the `-t` argument, so `| xargs cp -t /tmp/results` should work to copy them instead of moving them. As far as the find command goes, this actually looks like a pretty reasonable solution to me. I'm not sure what benefit it would have to have find somehow use the contents of /tmp/search.txt. Can you clarify by saying what you want this script to do differently from the version you posted?

Comment: The find command I posted will not work, I think the syntax is incorrect `mv: missing file operand
Try 'mv --help' for more information.`  I need to know how to tell find command to use the file

Comment: Interesting: that's what `mv` would say if you haven't listed any files to move. That sounds as though your perl script is not producing any output. I'd double check that first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just use the `search.txt` file as a list of patterns with `grep` directly:

```
find . -name '*.png' | grep -f search.txt | xargs ...
```

Or if you want to make the patterns more strict, you could do something like this:

```
find . -name '*.png' | grep -f <(sed s/^/[0-9]_[0-9]_[0-9]_/ search.txt)
```

Or even more strict with:

```
find . -name '*.png' | grep -f <(sed s?^?/[0-9]_[0-9]_[0-9]_? search.txt)
```

And even more strict with:

```
find . -name '*.png' | grep -f <(sed 's?.*?/[0-9]_[0-9]_[0-9]_&_?' search.txt)
```

In this last one, an entire line in `search.txt` is matched (`.*`), and in the replacement we prefix with the pattern `/[0-9]_[0-9]_[0-9]_`, followed by the matched string (`&`), followed by a `_`. So for example if you have the letter `A` as a pattern in `search.txt`, this will generate a pattern for that line as `/[0-9]_[0-9]_[0-9]_A_`, which will correctly match your file with `_A_` there.

If the output looks good, you can pipe it to `xargs` to copy the matched files like this:

```
... | xargs -i{} cp {} /path/to/dir
```

Comment: I will test this and report back..  Would the second example you posted automatically search the fourth pattern within .png filename's? This would be critical for the search to be correct..

Comment: I added a 3rd example for that.

Comment: Great janos, the third option worked perfect but it just listed the output to terminal, what would I have to add to that to copy all the files matching the argument to a new folder??

Comment: @linuxnoob You sould may be try mine pure perl and tested [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20360428/49197).

Comment: @ janos I did find one discrepancy while using `find . -name '*.png' | grep -f <(sed s?^?/[0-9]_[0-9]_[0-9]_? search.txt) | xargs -i{} cp {} /path/to/dir`  One of the entries in my search.txt was "A" on its own and with the line of code you gave me this led to a few files whose 4th string started with A being copied also..  The only way around this would be to search for an exact match of the 4th string & not just the first letter(s)..  So if there is a single character entry in the search.txt then the 4th string in the filename(s) must only be a single matching character..

Comment: @linuxnoob I added an even more strict version with explanation ;-)

Comment: Yes janos, that worked perfectly and because of the simplicity of it, I would have to pick your answer as the answer that most meets my needs..  Thankyou.

Answer (score 1):

Most efficient solution should be:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Basename; # no_chdir will cause we will get full path name
use File::Find;
use File::Copy;     # copy and move will work as shell's cp and mv

my ( $fn, $dir, $target ) = @ARGV; # script arguments

# check parameters
( stat($dir)    && -d _ ) or die "Not a dir $dir";
( stat($target) && -d _ ) or die "Not a dir $target";

# construct regexp for matching files
# use quotemeta to sanitize data read from $fn file 
my $re = join '|', map quotemeta, do {
    # open file
    open( my $fh, '<', $fn ) or die "$fn: $!";
    my @p = <$fh>;            # read all patterns
    close($fh);
    chomp @p;                 # remove end of line from patterns
    @p;                       # return of do statement
};
$re = qr/$re/;                # precompile regexp
# it makes trie for up to ten thousand patterns so match should be O(1)

sub wanted {
    my $fourth;
    lstat($_)                 # initialize special _ term
        && (
           -d _               # is directory? Return true so step in depth
        || -f _               # otherwise if is file
        && /\.png$/           # is filename in $_ ending .png
        # split by '_' to five pieces max and get fourth part (index 3) 
        && defined( $fourth = ( split '_', basename($_), 5 )[3] ) # check if defined 
        && $fourth =~ /^$re$/ # match regexp
        && do { move( $_, $target ) or die "$_: $!" } # then move using File::Copy::move
        );                    # change move to copy if you want copy file instead
}

# do not change directory so $target can be relative and move will still work well
find( { wanted => \&wanted, no_chdir => 1 }, $dir );
```

Usage

```
perl find_and_move.pl /tmp/search.txt . /tmp/results
```

Comment: Thankyou for your time Hynek -Pichi- Vychodil..  I am relatively new to linux & this solution scares me :) but also excites me.. can you explain if this is a normal .sh script and if so how I would specify the search.txt (list of pattern's), the folder to search in & the folder to copy matching files to? If this is a stand alone script outside of my master script, how would I call it?

Comment: That worked a treat Henek, Could you be so kind as to give me even a basic understanding of what is happening in this script?  It does the job 100% perfectly but I am none the wiser at to how it works :(  If it is too complicated or cumbersome to explain, can you point me in the direction of a good perl guide or tutorials, I was starting to come to terms with basic bash scripting but this absolutely fascinates me!!

Comment: @linuxnoob: I have added some comments. I hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

You use `my $pat = qr/$ARGV[0]/;`, but `$ARGV[0]` is `/tmp/search.txt`. You need to actually read the file.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

my $re = do {
   my $qfn = shift(@ARGV);
   open(my $fh, '<', $qfn) or die $!;
   chomp( my @pats = <$fh> );
   my $pat = join '|', map quotemeta, @pats;
   qr/^$pat\z/
};

while (<>) {
    my $tag = (split /_/)[3];
    next if !defined($tag);
    print if /$re/;
}
```

Comment: Thankyou ikegami, I want to test this but not sure how?  Is this a replacement of the match4th.pl in original question to run with this line? `find . -name '*.png' | perl match4th.pl '/tmp/search.txt' | xargs mv -t /tmp/results`

Comment: It is *is* `match4th.pl`, except it reads from patterns from the file passed to `$ARGV[0]`, like I said.e

Comment: All I did is fix the bug in match4th.pl and explained how I did so. As you can see, the only that changed is which file names it lets through.

Comment: Thankyou, I will test & report back